# Delphi TToolButton text Left alinement?

Tags: windows, delphi, button

Using Delphi 11.3.
I have a TToolbar with a *vertical* list of TToolButtons, in text mode.
During design time the text in the buttons is left-aligned.
During runtime he text in the buttons is Centered.

Is there any way that I can force the text to be left alinged, directly next to the Icons?

I found the drawing code in Vcl.ComCtrls, in procedure TToolBarStyleHook.Paint(Canvas: TCanvas);

```
 if (WStyle and TBSTYLE_LIST = TBSTYLE_LIST) then
      begin
        sRect := R;
        Canvas.Font := TControlClass(Control).Font;
        DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Info.pszText),
          Length(Info.pszText), sRect, DT_CENTER or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_CALCRECT);
        RectCenter(sRect, R);
        if ImageDrawed and (Info.iImage >= 0) and (FImages <> nil) then
        begin
          iRect := Rect(5, iRect.Top, FImages.Width + 5, iRect.Bottom);
          OffsetRect(iRect, R.Left, 0);
          sRect := Rect(iRect.Right + 3, sRect.Top, R.Right, sRect.Bottom);
        end;
        if DrawButtonFace then
          DrawControlText(Canvas, Details, Info.pszText, sRect, DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK)
        else
        begin
          if ButtonState <> ttbButtonDisabled then
            Canvas.Font.Color := LStyle.GetSystemColor(clBtnText)
          else
            Canvas.Font.Color := LStyle.GetSystemColor(clGrayText);
          SetBkMode(Canvas.Handle, Transparent);
          DrawText(Canvas.Handle, Info.pszText, Length(Info.pszText), sRect,
            DT_LEFT or DT_WORDBREAK);
        end;
      end
```

Now if DT_CENTER would instead be DT_LEFT my problem would likely be solved...
Would there be any way to override this?

Comment: Bart, `TToolbarStylehook` is involved only if a style is applied. Which style are you using?

Comment: The code you refer to, (`TToolBarStyleHook.Paint(Canvas: TCanvas);`) is used only if styles are used. If you refer to the first `DrawText()`, note the modifier `DT_CALCRECT` which means this call is only used to measure the text if later drawn. The actual drawing, later in the code, is done with `DT_LEFT`. Please, provide a separately created and **simplified** [mre] that shows *your* actual code, including form properties (`.dfm` file).

Comment: Sorry Tom, I use no styles at all. Plain XP based code, plain TToolbar with TToolbuttons on it.  But I just found what changes the final behaviour: I had the TToolbar 'Allow Text Buttons' not checked. This still works perfectly with all my text buttons... But changing this setting caused the text alignment to go Left. I will answer my own question now..

Answer (score 0):

The text alignment of 'Text Buttons' changes when the Toolbar option 'Allow Text Button' is changed. Despite the fact that the Text buttons are working fine if this option is NOT checked. But it does change the text alignment...